# How to resolve error 'only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' for forecasting future values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run a code in order to make predictions from a data set that I have so that I can create an AR model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import scipy
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Matlab-style plotting
import seaborn as sns
color = sns.color_palette()
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import Series 
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR

def difference(dataset):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
        value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - 1])      
            diff.append(value)
    return numpy.array(diff)


def predict(coef, history):
    yhat = coef[0]
    for i in range(1, len(coef)):
        yhat += coef[i] * history[-i]
    return yhat


series = df1
# split dataset
X = difference(series.values)
size = int(len(X) * 0.7)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:]
# train autoregression
model = AR(train)
model_fit = model.fit(maxlag=6, disp=False)
window = model_fit.k_ar
coef = model_fit.params
# walk forward over time steps in test
history = [train[i] for i in range(len(train))]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    yhat = predict(coef, history)
    obs = test[t]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    history.append(obs)
error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
# plot
pyplot.plot(test)
pyplot.plot(predictions, color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

However, I get the error message:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d957122afe98> in <module>()
      1 series = CSPSearch
      2 # split dataset
----> 3 X = difference(series.values)
      4 size = int(len(X) * 0.7)
      5 train, test = X[0:size], X[size:]

<ipython-input-11-0aa854a16333> in difference(dataset)
      3     for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
      4        # value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]
----> 5         value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - 1])
      6         diff.append(value)
      7     return numpy.array(diff)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error as I am following an example from online which seems to work fine however I am receiving this error :(
Any possible help?

Comment: Can you include the `import` statements? What libraries are you using?

Comment: You haven't even shown the `difference` function that is throwing the error. But that code is really not very good, if it's straight from an online example you should find a better site.

Comment: @RSem Please put your code inside the question

Comment: I have edited the code in the question as per comments

Comment: Your dataframe, `series`, must contain strings (object dtype). `series.values` will then be an object dtype array, and your `difference` function tries to subtract one string from another (or list/array of strings), which doesn't work.  We can't help without a clear idea of what that `df1` dataframe is like.  The rest of the code isn't important.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, df1 looks like this for example: `1 2018-09-04 XOB1 201 .... 2 2018-09-06 XOB1 199 ..... 3 2018-09-08 XOB1 57`... with the columns as (ID, Day, Name, Count). Hope this makes it clearer to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value = float(dataset[i]) - float(dataset[i - 1])
```

Instead of:

```
value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]
```

Comment: I ran this as suggested however get the error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Could you post the whole trackback of the error, please??

Comment: Traceback <ipython-input-40-d957122afe98> in <module>()
      1 series = CSPSearch
      2 # split dataset
----> 3 X = difference(series.values)
      4 size = int(len(X) * 0.7)
      5 train, test = X[0:size], X[size:]

<ipython-input-39-f7825a6cc35d> in difference(dataset)
      3     for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
      4        # value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]
----> 5         value = float(dataset[i]) - float(dataset[i - 1])
      6         diff.append(value)
      7     return numpy.array(diff)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Is there a way to make the previous comment clearer in a code format?

Comment: It's ok... I get it. Could you show me the type and shape of `series.values`, please? The type can be found using `print(type(series.values))` and the shape can be found using `series.values.shape`.

Comment: When running 'print(type(series.values))' - I get: 
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>  then with series.values.shape - I get: (52, 4)

Comment: I think I know the reason, does `series` contain the header of the dataframe??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I wanted to use the series function to call the dataframe: df1 however the only code I could find was: series = Series.from_csv('file1.csv', header = 0) however was not sure if there would be a way to use the Series function to read a dataframe and the headers?

Comment: No, use `df1 = pandas.read_csv('file1.csv', index_col=False, header=0)` instead

Comment: Is there a function instead of pandas.read_csv which can read an existing df I have already created?

Comment: what do you mean by an existing df??

Comment: So I created a dataframe called "df1" which I used to filter through the original data set from a dataframe called "Data" - In df1, this is the dataframe which has the filtered values that I wanted to only use for predicting the future values instead of using the original CSV file. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: I guess the shape of `df1` is the same as `series` which is (52, 4). Could you print the first three rows??

Comment: Yes exactly, so 'series' should contain the same data within 'df1'.. Here is a snippet of a row from df1: `1          2018-09-04          XOB1         201` `2     2018-09-06    XOB1    199` `3     2018-09-08     XOB1   57`- The headers are as follows: ID, Day, Name and Count (Apologies as I'm not really sure how to add a code within the comments section)

Comment: It's ok.. You can't add code in the comments :) Anyway, what is the expected output from `dataset[1] - dataset[0]`??

Comment: According to the website I am following, the purpose of the code is to transform the differencing

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-predictions-time-series-forecasting-python/ This is the link I am using for the example

Comment: As you can see the dataset used in the provided link was (Day, Count) not (ID, Day, Name, Count)

Comment: Yes I am aware, I wanted to use their example to guide the work that I was doing so my dataset contains the columns (ID, Day, Name, Count).. I used the codes from the website to run against my own dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a dataframe like yours (you could have made this step easier!)

```
In [12]: d=[[1, '2018-09-04', 'XOB1', 201],[2, '2018-09-06', 'XOB1', 199], [3, '
    ...: 2018-09-08', 'XOB1', 57]]                                              
In [13]: d                                                                      
Out[13]: 
[[1, '2018-09-04', 'XOB1', 201],
 [2, '2018-09-06', 'XOB1', 199],
 [3, '2018-09-08', 'XOB1', 57]]
In [14]: col=('ID', 'Day', 'Name', 'Count')                                     

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=col)                                 
In [17]: df                                                                     
Out[17]: 
   ID         Day  Name  Count
0   1  2018-09-04  XOB1    201
1   2  2018-09-06  XOB1    199
2   3  2018-09-08  XOB1     57
In [18]: df.dtypes                                                              
Out[18]: 
ID        int64
Day      object
Name     object
Count     int64
dtype: object
```

The dataframe is a mix of strings (dtype object) and numbers.

`values` is a numpy array; the only common dtype is `object`:

```
In [19]: v = df.values                                                          
In [20]: v                                                                      
Out[20]: 
array([[1, '2018-09-04', 'XOB1', 201],
       [2, '2018-09-06', 'XOB1', 199],
       [3, '2018-09-08', 'XOB1', 57]], dtype=object)
```

If we pass this to your `difference` function, it will try to take the difference between successive rows, after trying to convert the row to an integer:

```
In [21]: v[0]                                                                   
Out[21]: array([1, '2018-09-04', 'XOB1', 201], dtype=object)
In [22]: float(v[0])                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a2aadf8cab7b> in <module>
----> 1 float(v[0])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Python `int()` doesn't work on an list, and it won't work on a string like 'XOB1'.  Same for `float()`.  (Adapting tutorial code is a lot easier if you start with some familiarity with the underlying language!)

We can instead look at the numeric Series, `Count`:

```
In [23]: df.Count.values                                                        
Out[23]: array([201, 199,  57])

In [25]: def difference(dataset): 
    ...:     diff = list() 
    ...:     for i in range(1, len(dataset)): 
    ...:         value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - 1]       
    ...:         diff.append(value) 
    ...:     return numpy.array(diff) 
    ...:
```

Now `difference` happily works with this array of numbers, even without the `int`:

```
In [26]: difference(df.Count.values)                                            
Out[26]: array([  -2, -142])
```

There's a builtin `diff` function:
    In [27]: np.diff(df.Count.values)
    Out[27]: array([  -2, -142])

which does:

```
In [28]: v = df.Count.values                                                    
In [29]: v[1:]-v[:-1]                                                           
Out[29]: array([  -2, -142])
```

I glanced at https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html

Have you seriously tried to understand the inputs that this model expects?